# Mailjet - Perform string and array manipulation

Tags: arrays, string, templating, mailjet

I couldn’t find an answer to my question, including on the Mailjet documentation so here I am. Can someone tell me if it is possible (and if so, how) in Mailjet's templating language to :

- check if a variable contains a specific string
- add an element to an array
- check if an array is empty?

Thank you a lot for your time